# What are the effects of using Django models as global variables in views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here I have written 2 views functions. If there is any difference between these, could you please explain which one will be fast?

#Views1.py

```
def myview1(request):
  q=mymodel.objects.all()
  .
  .
  #rest of the code
  return response
```

#Views2.py

```
x=mymodel.objects.all()

def myview2(request):
  q=x
  .
  .
  #rest of the code
  return response
```

Suppose 'mymodel' is not updating, in this case using queryset as a global variable so that multiple view functions can use it without hitting the database for each request is a good idea?? Any kind of extra help/idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why use the database if the data is not changed? And if it is indeed modified, you don't want to "cache" it this way. In general, ANY global variable is a bad idea unless you know what are you doing (i.e. threadlocals has their purpose in certain cases)

Comment: As for the "fast" - both of them unless you can measure performance issues. Do not optimize before you can feel the problems.

Comment: I just want to know that if we use querysets as globals then will it reduce database load or not. As I am thinking (maybe I am wrong) it's better to use global querysets so that multiple functions can use it, instead each function hit the database for each new request - @AlexandrTatarinov